# iphone SDK::: It is possible we use XSLT in iphone sdk, if it is possible than how can we use it

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am iphone developer but never use any **XSLT** in iPhone SDK , can you advice me , how can we use **XSLT** , **XML** through sQlite.

Comment: What would the need be? XSLT is a transform dialect used best for changing an XML document into a different format. While you could use an iPhone to consume XML content, I struggle to understand the benefit of transforming it. Maybe answer with a potential use case?

Comment: Thanks Cliff,But My PM told me to do that, They want good searching speed in Iphone App.We are using Big XML through SQLITE in App, but they told me, it is not good speed`to searching in app.It's take a time near about 15 Second, when load the app that's why they told me use XSLT XML through SQLITE, IT is possible or not , If possible then what it benefit or loss, IF you have time please let meknow, Thanks KD –